# FullPage.JS One page scroll not working on mobile phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-plugins, fullpage.js

On mobile devices fullpageJS is working like a normal scrolling page.I tried everything to make the one-page scroll effect persistent on mobile but nothing is happening.this is the
[Link](http://surveykong.xyz/)

on which my file is uploaded.Please help me Someone.I'm out of ideas and direction now.
here's my code i have used to initialise the script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'forthPage', 'fifthPage', 'sixthPage'],
    sectionsColor: ['#222222', '#333333', '#222222', '#333333','#222222', '#333333'],
    navigation: true,
    slidesNavigation: true,
    navigationPosition: 'right',
    navigationTooltips: ['Page1', 'Page2', 'Page3', 'Page4','Page5','Page6'],
    responsive: 768,
    keyboardScrolling: true,
    recordHistory: false,
    scrollBar:true,
    css3: true,
    touchSensitivity: 15,
    normalScrollElementTouchThreshold: 5,
    responsive: 0,
    scrollingSpeed: 1200,
    easingcss3: 'cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275)'
});
```

});

Answer (score 2):

Definetelly not a fullpage.js problem. You can easily check the [demo page](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) to see how it works as expected.

Your problem seem to be in the use of the `responsive` option. You are probably setting the dimensions too hight for your device. (`responsive: 768,`)

Also, you should be using `responsiveWidth` or `responsiveHeight` as `responsive` is no longer [in the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) as it is deprecated.